# Get multiple feeds from Facebook with Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've done my best to find the answer, but nothings seems to cover what I'm trying to do. I know how to get a single feed, from say a fan page like Starbucks, or Pepsi using the Graph API. What I want to do  is get several, or multiple, feeds in a single request. Is this possible? I was told by another developer that it is, but haven't found anything on this subject in the FB documentation, or anywhere else online. I have like 50 feeds I want to aggregate into a single feed, and I don't want to make 50 different requests to get all that data.

Has anyone know how to do this, or know if it's even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After ever MORE searching, apparently you can do this. You do this by using Batch Requests:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Hope this will save someone time in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't really.

This works:

```
SELECT page_id 
  FROM page 
 WHERE username='facebook' 
    OR username='coca-cola'

{
  "data": [
    {
      "page_id": 20531316728
    }, 
    {
      "page_id": 40796308305
    }
  ]
}
```

---

This works (~100 results):

```
SELECT post_id,message 
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id IN (
    SELECT page_id 
      FROM page 
     WHERE username='facebook' 
) LIMIT 100
```

---

But this doesn't really works (3 results):

```
SELECT post_id,message 
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id IN (
    SELECT page_id 
      FROM page 
     WHERE username='facebook' 
        OR username='coca-cola'
) LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I just figured out that they allow something called Batching, which will accomplish what I'm trying to do. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Thought you wanted a single FQL query. Glad you found what you wanted.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I wanted a single HTTP request. Thanks again though.